# Most effective "free trial" button copy

Tags: buttons, copywriting

Are there any studies comparing the click-through rate for various free trial button labels? For example "Start free 30-day trial" vs. "Try now".

Comment: all I could find is https://marketingexperiments.com/copywriting/cta-button-copy-reduce-clickthrough, but I'm worried that the button size might have affected the outcome

Comment: This is likely going to be unique to your specific use case—target audience, platform, industry, ..... These are all factors that could greatly impact your findings of which has the highest click-through.

Comment: one more article I found: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/changing-one-word-increased-revenue-330000/133985/

Comment: Also, here's a collection of AB test results for button copy: http://www.platonik.co.uk/platonik-blog/call-to-action#10

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the free trial is for, who the target is, but it's not a bad idea to  use the word "now" in a CTA. The first CTA "Start..." is a bit long, but long isn't universally bad. It does have the word "free" going for it. I always like the use of a personal pronoun. "Start my free 30-day trial" is even better. To improve upon that you could try the word Get instead of start. Get is pretty much a universally effective CTA verb. People love getting stuff.

One concern with free trials is whether people will have to give their credit card info. I don't have the research, but I think there's a higher click through rate for ones that don't require CC. If a CC isn't required, make sure that's somewhere clear on the landing page near the CTA (but not below, as there shouldn't be any relevant copy below the CTA for ADA best practices). Make the no-CC info prominent--it's important.

(Sorry just realized this is from Nov 2017--better late than never on the reply?)

Comment: Agree with making "no CC needed" prominent if that _is_ the case. Far too many "free trials" are really "_subscribe with the option of cancelling if you remember to do so_" that I would assume the latter unless there's clear indication otherwise.